# Cordova: You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Tags: android, apache-cordova, mobile

A dois dias tento resolver mas não obtive sucesso.

O comando usado foi o "cordova run android"

Segue abaixo mensagem que aparece quando tento rodar Cordova no *device*:

> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: "E:\Projetos\Livraria-direito\platforms\android\assets" not located within project!
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Comment: Você pode fornecer mais informações? Com qual comando você tentou executar o Cordova? Você tem certeza que dentro da pasta `E:\Projetos\Livraria-direito\platforms\` existe uma pasta chamada Android e que ela não está vazia?

Comment: No teu `config.xml` tens a tag da plataforma: `<platform name="android"></platform>` ?